# Is an HTML5 data-element-id per DOM element going too far?

Tags: html, dom, custom-data-attribute

In order to track an almost entirely dynamic DOM layout I am considering using the HTML5 data attribute to track elements.

Would placing one on each DOM element begin to affect load performance, or negatively affect other searching mechanisms such as `getElementById` or `$(#Selector)`?

Comment: Any reason you can't store them in, say, an array?

Comment: I don't see why it should. The data elements are processed with the rest of the document on page load and once they're processed, they're the same as any other DOM attribute. I don't think there's a performance impact here. I could be wrong tho.

Comment: @minitech - Are you suggesting that data attributes be deprecated in favor of javascript arrays?

Comment: @TravisJ: No, I'm suggesting that an array is a data structure much more appropriate for storing lists of items than a tree. So I'm asking you if it's a list or a tree you want (or neither).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not affect any other searching mechanism. As far as load performance goes, if you were to measure it down to the microsecond, sure... The more markup gets rendered, the slower it will be. If you're talking about data- attributes, the difference is probably negligible.